# Minecraft Repeating Command Block constantly /tp me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am in this minecraft world and I was messing around with a command block right next to my build and accidently /tp myself to a random location and it was a repeating block so I am stuck, HELP!

Comment: scrap the world or load it up in a map editor and clear the command block.

Answer (score 4):

There is a few options available to you.

1: Just delete the world. Although I doubt you want to do this.

2: delete the command block with mcedit.
You can download it from

```
http://www.mcedit.net/
```

which is the official site. (mcedit is a world editor)

3: Upload your world onto a server and then disable command blocks in the server properties. This will stop the command block from running thus you can then delete the command block.

4: if you know the general area that you put the command block you can use a `/fill` command to fill the area and delete the command block. (this only works if you know the general cords of where you put the command block.)